# django: trying to access my robots.txt: "TypeError at /robots.txt 'str' object is not callable"

Tags: python, django

Exception Type: TypeError at /robots.txt

Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable

What gives?

Views:

```
ROBOTS_PATH = os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'robots.txt')


def robots(request):
""" view for robots.txt file """
return HttpResponse(open(ROBOTS_PATH).read(), 'text/plain')
```

Settings:

```
CURRENT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__).decode('utf-8'))
```

URLs:

```
(r'^robots\.txt$', 'robots'),
```

Comment: You can't seriously expect us to answer this question without any information about your code, can you? We need a traceback and probably a relevant excerpt of the program.

Comment: Added the code. been a long day. stupid neighbors had me up till 3am then woke me up in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
from appname.views import robots
(r'^robots\.txt$', robots),
```

Or:

```
(r'^robots\.txt$', 'projectname.appname.views.robots'),
```

Django can't figure out where your `'robots'` function is.